# Why does my textarea's blur event not get fired before my jQuery UI dialog is closed?

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, textarea, modal-dialog

I have a textarea element inside of a jquery modal dialog that has an attached blur handler.  The blur handler code is triggered correctly in Chrome and Internet Explorer when the click of the button on the dialog, which calls `$('#mydialog).dialog('destroy').remove();` occurs.

Unfortunately, in Firefox this is not happening!

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to eventually resolve the issue by utilizing `setTimeout` to wrap the click handler code in, which allowed enough time for the blur event on the textarea to fire properly.

The resulting code was as follows:

`var c = $('#mydialog'); 
setTimeout(function() {c.dialog('destroy').remove();}, 1);`

As it turns out so far, a 1ms timeout is just enough to force the appropriate context switch in the browser to allow for the blur event to occur before the element is removed from the DOM.